# How to #include a single line in C

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Apperantly rumor has it that it is possible to #include a single line in C (possibly with gcc)

e.g.

```
#include <file.h> 5
```

To get like line 5. Cannot find anything like that in the cpp docs.

Or which preprocessors allow doing ugly hacks like that?!

Comment: I heard the same rumor, sadly it doesn't appear to be true. You'll have to write your own code preprocessor.

Answer (score 5):

I've never heard of such a feature, and I have certainly not come across any preprocessors that would support it.

In any case, it sounds like a *really* bad idea. What if someone inserted a blank line at the top of `file.h`... would you be happy for that change to break your program?

If you control `file.h`, I think the best approach is to extract line 5 into a separate header, and `#include` it both into `file.h` and into your main program.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible with GCC or any other compiler for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you confused it with

```
#line lineno filename
```

directive?

Comment: Well, "confused": that's probably what he wanted.

Comment: #line is nice to know, it modifies the apparent place of error (e.g. origin of source code line). We are having a debate in the office. One guy claims it is possible in ProC/Oracle & gcc. But we can't prove him wrong so far ;-)

Comment: @Dima: easy: he has to prove himself right, not the other way around.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, true. I do not think it's really in the spirit of c++.

Comment: @buddhabrot, not sure what you meant, but I was referring to the rumor, I'm not sure the OP wants it.

Comment: @michael sorry, I always thought #line did exactly what the OP wanted, hence my comment. Apparently not!

Comment: @buddhabrot, I see. Actually, the OP wanted to verify the rumor, i believe :)

Answer (score 1):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html#Include-Syntax

not possible with gcc and if it is possible with some compiller's preprocessor
it will create absolute mess.

Answer (score 0):

you'd simply create a one line file if you want something portable -- i too don't know of a means to accomplish exactly what you are after otherwise.

Comment: Isn't the minimum 2 lines because files must end with a blank line?

Comment: @Pubby No.  The file must end with a complete line, however; if the last character in the file isn't `'\n'`, when reading the file in text mode, then the behavior is undefined.  (Confusion probably occurs because many Windows programs treat the CRLF as a line separator, and not as a line terminator.  As far as I can tell, this is not the case of the libraries in Visual Studios, however.)

Comment: @James: _was_ undefined. Defined in C++11.

Comment: @MSalters Now I wonder why they changed that:-).  (And does that mean that you can't use `istream` or `FILE*` in text mode to read the input?)

Comment: @James: Presumably because you'd want to avoid silly UB, i.e. cases that are trivially detectable. I'd have to check if `std::istream` is changed similarly, but you'd indeed have issues writing your C++11 compiler in C++'98

Comment: @MSalters My question was meant to be rhetorical.  Getting rid of undefined behavior is always a plus.